# Passkit pass will not download to device

Tags: ios, passbook

I am trying to host a very simple webpage that has a link to a passkit file on the server.
My goal is that users visit this page and click on an image and safari detects the pass and downloads it.

For testing purposes both the HTML file and the pass are in the same directory, here is the simple html page that I am using to link to the pass:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<a mimetype="application/vnd.apple.pkpass"  href="pass.pkpass">
<img src="pass.jpg" />
</a>
</html>
```

For some reason this is failing, and I am getting a message in safari saying that it cannot download the file.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

I have emailed the pass to myself to test and it notices it when I open it in mail and adds it to passbook just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the server understands the mime type, like this other post?

[Sharing Passbook Passes .pkpass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610296/sharing-passbook-passes-pkpass)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to me that .pkpass files can't be served up from static links into Mobile Safari, the response must have some headers set. Here is what I do:

The server responding to the link must set the Content-Type and Content-Length headers to the 'application/vnd.apple.pkpass' and length of the .pkpass file. My code also sets the Content-Disposition header to 'attachment; ' + filename_header to signify to Mobile Safari that the content needs to be downloaded.

Comment: I am experiencing similar issue. I am sending pkpass as an email attachment.
Now, for some reason client is not able to download it when accessed in Safari@IPhone.

Comment: I do not attempt that because email programs are bad at determining correct mimetypes for attachments and doing the right thing. Instead, I send a link in the email to the server that will respond as noted above with the correct headers in the response.